# Hydrodehalogenation of aryl chlorides

Tags: organic-chemistry, transition-metals, hydrogen, catalysis

Palladium is the "go to" heterogeneous catalyst for dehalogenating aryl chlorides using hydrogen. What are the chemical (not economic) reasons for other precious metal catalysts not being as common or as efficient in this reaction e.g. rhodium?